# Преобразование в UTF-8

Tags: php, delphi

В Delphi имеем

```
var Str: RawByteString;
Str := UTF8Encode('Саша');
```

Получаем 8 байт `Ord(Str[I])`
208 161 208 176 209 136 208 176
Как получить те же байты (строку) в PHP?

```
$Str = ???('Саша');
```

Пробовал `utf8_encode`, `mb_convert_encoding`, `iconv`, перебираю строку в PHP и `Ord(SubStr($Str,$i,1))` дает другие коды символов и больше.
PHP 5 версии.

Comment: а исходная строка у вас в какой кодировке. проще всего просто открыть php в редакторе в котором стоит кодировка utf8 и написать просто 'Саша'

Comment: Вот, например https://ideone.com/X10RXN

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r(unpack('C*', iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', 'Саша')));
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 208
    [2] => 161
    [3] => 208
    [4] => 176
    [5] => 209
    [6] => 136
    [7] => 208
    [8] => 176
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Всем спасибо. Просто запутался в кодировках файлов... поэтому тупил :(
Если файл в windows-1251, то

```
$s = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', 'Саша');
$s = mb_convert_encoding('Саша', "utf-8", "windows-1251");
```

дают нужный результат.